# Can't replace Plesk's default Apache page

Tags: apache, plesk

I'm trying to change the default page for Apache (not the default one on .skel) and I just can't find it.

Most places I found on my search just point me to change the default page for a new domain/hosting plan while I want to change this one:

[image]

Where can I locate this and change this index file?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the file I needed to play with: `/var/www/error/noindex.html`